# Continuity of $f(z) = Log z$ , for $z$ complex, non-real $-\ln|z|$, for $z$ real

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, continuity

At what points in the complex plane is this function continuous (If there is any)?

> Would it be correct to conclude that $f$ is then continuous for all $z$ in the complex plane less the real numbers? If so, how could one formalise this argument?

My efforts:
Since we want to find all points where $f$ is continuous, I want to try and visualise the points where it should be continuous. 
Now $-ln|z|$ is continuous for all $z$ real and non-zero as far as I am aware. And we can't get $Logz$ (where we are talking about the principal logarithm) to be continuous unless we take a branch cut. The natural one being to take out the negative real numbers, and $0$. However, I am confused about the negativity part of $-ln|z|$ as I think it might make $f$ discontinuous for positive real numbers also?

(Taken from a past Complex Analysis (really an introduction) exam in my second year undergraduate course)

Comment: You can cut the plane in any manner you like provided the contour that cuts the plane terminates at $z=0$.  Then, given a particular branch of the plane, the logarithm will be continuous ... just don't cross the contour that cuts the plane.

Comment: @ Dr. MV I thought that $Argz$ was defined to be in $(-pi,pi]$ so that you had to take the branch cut of the principal logarithm by taking out the negative real numbers and $0$. Or is that just my own misconception?

Comment: No.  You can even cut along curved contours.  There are applications for which this is prudent.

Comment: @ Dr. MV Thank you, but could you please perhaps give an example of a "curved contour" for which we can cut along, I'm having a little trouble doing one myself.

Comment: $y=x^2$ for $x\ge 0$ is one of an infinite number of possibilities.  So is $y=0$ for $x\ge 0$.  And yet a third would be the kinked cut $y=0$ for $0\le x\le 1$, and then $x=1$ for $y\ge 0$.  The choice is predicated on the application.

Comment: @ Dr. MV Thank you, I understand the first two, though I am having trouble with the last. We say $y=0$ for $0\le x \le 1$ but that means $x=1$ since $y$ is $0$, so it is greater than or equal to $0$. How does this work?

Comment: That last one has two segments.  A small one on the real axis between $0$ and $1$ and then one that starts at $(1,0)$ and extends vertically to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the discussion in the comments gives an answer the original question. You have a specific function $f$ defined on $\mathbb {C}\setminus \{0\}.$ Since $f(z) = \log z, z \in \mathbb {C}\setminus \mathbb {R},$ we know $f$ is continuous at each point of that set. (Here $\log z$ is the principal value logarithm.) So we now consider real $z.$ We know $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ because of the behavior of $\log z.$ If $z>0,$ what happens? Well here $\log z = \ln |z|,$ but $f(z) = -\ln |z|.$ So there is no hope for continuity unless $z =1.$ You can check that indeed $f$ is continuous at $1.$ For $z<0,$ forget about it: As you approach any such $z$ from above, the imaginary part of $f$ tends to $\pi.$ But $f(z)$ is real for such $z,$ so no chance. Summary: $f$ is continuous at $z$ iff $z  \in (\mathbb {C}\setminus \mathbb {R}) \cup \{1\}.$